# Export an attachment from sfdc to SFTP server

Tags: integration, attachment

We have a requirement to keep the attachment(like pdf,doc,etc) in salesforce and also in a SFTP server.

Just assume, we are uploading a file to salesforce and clicking on a save button....now that file will be saved in salesforce also will be placed in a Folder in SFTP Server.

Please suggest a solution on how can the above be achieved ?

Comment: solutions other than http://www.chiragmehta.info/chirag/2010/03/22/salesforce-ftp-integration-data-loader-web-service-http/

Comment: Are you creating the attachment natively in Salesforce or via an API call from an external web service? Do you have server resources outside of Salesforce that could host a web service or a scheduled job to periodically poll Salesforce? How current does the FTP store need to be? Could it be a few minutes/hours/days behind the data in Salesforce?

Comment: Daniel Ballinger: The attachment should first be created in salesforce and when we click on the save button, the attachment should be pushed to the SFTP server.
There should not be any delay in data transfer.
I appreciate your response and kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: I don't think you will find a native Salesforce solution that supports SFTP. You will need some external service to integrate with the SFTP server.